# Application is set to remember its settings, but has problem with the very first launch

Tags: qt, qml, settings

I'm using QML [Settings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) to make application remember a SpinBox input value:

```
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

SpinBox {
    id: dimensionSpinBox
    to: 5000
    stepSize: 1
    from: 1
}

Settings {
    // Value is remembered by QML in a settings file somewhere
    category: "App_Dimension_Input"
    property alias dimension: dimensionSpinBox.value
}
```

[image: SpinBox]

#### Problem 1

On the very first launch of the app by a user, when there is no settings file available, the SpinBox value becomes either minimum `from` or maximum `to` which creates a bizarre situation in the application due to dependency of some features on the `SpinBox` value. Minimum and maximum are not desirable, but a reasonable value would be something like `125`.

#### Solve problem 1

I solve *problem 1* by adding these to SpinBox:

```
SpinBox {
    // ...
    value: 125
    Component.onCompleted: {
        value = Qt.binding(function(){return 125})
    }
}
```

Now on the very first launch by user, application starts with SpinBox value set to a reasonable of `125`.

#### Problem 2

Having solved problem 1, another problem arises: the application won't remember SpinBox value in future launches and always sets it to `125`!

#### How?

How to solve problem 1 and problem 2 at the same time?

- On the very first launch, when there is no settings file, set SpinBox value to a reasonable one
- On later launches, when there is a settings file, remember previously-set SpinBox value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `Component.onCompleted: value = Qt.binding(function(){return 125})` line, that's what is overriding the settings value.
Just normally declaratively binding is sufficient :

```
SpinBox {
    id: dimensionSpinBox
    to: 5000
    stepSize: 1
    from: 1
    value: 125 // the initial value when no settings has been saved
}

Settings {
    category: "App_Dimension_Input"
    property alias dimension: dimensionSpinBox.value
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As far as I remember,  I tried it before, but let me try again ...

Comment: That was it! Thanks!